# Обращение к модели entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

```
 private client clients = new client();
    public kabinet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = clients;
       
    }

      private void vvod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cli = from client in vavlab1Entities.GetContext().clients select client;
        cli.FirstOrDefault().FIO_client = @class.FIO_client;
        cli.FirstOrDefault().number = num.Text;
        cli.FirstOrDefault().e_mail = email.Text;

         
        vavlab1Entities.GetContext().clients.AddOrUpdate(cli.FirstOrDefault());
        vavlab1Entities.GetContext().SaveChanges();
```

}

При выполнении этого кода выводит ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам ведь уже сказали что не так, да и ошибка весьма доходчиво говорит что не так, вам даже дали ссылку на дубликат, где подробно сказано почему эта ошибка возникает. Но вместо того, чтоб понять, вы задали по новой вопрос, добавив в него кучу лишнего. Вот что не понятного в том, что `cli.FirstOrDefault()` вернул вам пустоту (`null`)? Что мешает взять. поставить точку остановки, запустить, навести мышью, и глянуть что там вообще..?

Comment: В вашей БД в таблице client пусто, нет данных, ни одной строки. Совсем нет!

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/2.1.php

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, уже поняла. В этом и была проблема. Спасибо.